# Concatenate ncdf files and chunk on record dimension (nco)

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4, nco

I am trying to concatenate a large (~4000) number of ncdf files into a single file. Each input file is a spatial raster, with a x and y dimension.

I am trying to work with ncecat:

```
ncecat -4 -L 5 -D 2 --open_ram --cnk_csh=1000000000 \
   --cnk_dmn record,2000 --cnk_dmn x,10 --cnk_dmn y,10 \
   $input_files output.nc
```

This gives me something like this:

> netcdf test { dimensions:
> record = UNLIMITED ; // (6 currently)
> y = 11250 ;
> x = 15000 ; variables:
> float Band1(record, y, x) ;
> Band1:long_name = "GDAL Band Number 1" ;
> Band1:_FillValue = -3.4e+38f ;
> Band1:grid_mapping = "transverse_mercator" ;
> Band1:_Storage = "chunked" ;
> Band1:_ChunkSizes = 1, 10, 10 ;
> Band1:_DeflateLevel = 5         Band1:_Filter = "|1,5 ;
> Band1:_Shuffle = "true" ;
> Band1:_Endianness = "little" ;

, and the record dimension was not actually chunked.
I think I can run this command first, and then use ncks on the output file to fix the record dim and rechunk again, however, as ncks needs to read everything into ram, and is also another time-costly operation, I am searching a way to tell ncecat that it should also consider the record-dim as a chunking dimension. I haven't found a way to do this yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your command looks well-formed, though there are a few comments I would make. First, the behavior you are seeing may be a bug, since the command should produce record dimension chunks of size 2000 as request. Second, please read the chunking documentation [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#cnk). This leads to the possibility that adding the `--cnk_plc=cnk_xpl` option may help. Third, I suggest you concatenate and chunk the files with `ncrcat` not `ncecat`. The former is less memory-intensive than the latter, as described [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#mmr).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I will try --cnk_plc=cnk_xpl / using ncrcat